# Wrapping text and div as a unit

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have the following that I would like wrapped as units.

```
<div class='tag-box'>
   <a href=#>Axe Committee</a>
   <div class='circle'><a href=#>x</a></div>
</div>
```

The CSS for these classes are:

```
.tag-box {
  display:inline;
}

.circle {
  display:inline;
  padding-left:4px;
  padding-right:4px;
  background:rgb(196,15,24); /*dark red*/
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}

.circle a {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;

  position:relative; top:-2px;
}
```

I can have upwards of 20 or 30 of these tag-boxes displayed inline. The problem is that the wrapping will break the words from each other or even break the red circle from the link. This makes it hard to differentiate which circle belongs to which link. (In the future, each circle corresponds to a different action with respect to the link.) See below.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f0c5a72ac9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f0c5a72ac9.png)

How do I prevent this kind of wrapping from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0: Use `white-space: nowrap;`.

1: You could have the circle as background of your .tag-box (or your .circle a). eg:

```
.tag-box {
  display: inline;
  background-image: url('circe.png');
  background-position: 100%; /* Display to the right */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 10px /* To leave space for the image */
}
```

2: You could use fixed-size floating .tag-box-es ( :/ )

3: You could have a (ready made) script put a circle on the right of every ".circle a"

Answer (score 2):

You want each of your `.tag-box` to be *inline* (not taking all the width available) but still being considered as a *block* (its content shouldn't be cut in half). Here enters ... *inline-block*!

Here is a complete HTML code: http://pastebin.com/24tG7tCz

I used a *list* of links to better represent the lists of couple of links tag+action (bad news: you've a [divitis syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div#Overuse) ;))

I also added *title*s: your '`x`' links aren't accessible at all and can be confusing for everybody, with or without any handicap, because one is never sure if the x will suppress the tag on the left or on the right: there are dozens of links, each with the text '`x`'! A *title* attribute on the a element tells blind users and everybody else via a tooltip what'll really do that x.

With a `span` inside a.x, you can change the `background-color` on `hover` and `focus`, it wouldn't be possible with a inside a *span* or *div*.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

.tag-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

Although you may experience some issues with firefox 2 and older versions of IE

Comment: You're right, I forgot Fx2 in my code. Two lines of CSS : display: -moz-inline-stack; preceding display: inline-block; may be sufficient, except when links are sort of disabled in Fx2. In that case, the element must have an unique child, so in the code I provided you must add a div child of li and parent of both links.